# Unit test Execution Results in SonarQube server

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

This is regarding the unit test case execution result in SonarQube server.

I don't have the actual solution file of the product but just the execution results which should be converted from the .log file to Sonarqube generic format.

I had uploaded the files successfully into SonarQube server. Now How to display the execution results or where do I can see the execution results? As per the requirement, none other code analysis is required. Just the Unit test case execution results needs to be displayed. How to set a dashboard with the Unit test case execution results?

Best regards,
Salini S.

Comment: This is a broad question. Have you read any tutorials at all? SO is meant to answer questions about specific programming (and related) problems. Please tell us what you have already tried.

Comment: Hi, I have the unit test case results in generic format. And then the properties file. Executed the commands. Execution was successful. The unit test results were not displayed in the sonar server. The properties file content is as follows.                                                      
sonar.host.url=<Serverlink>
sonar.projectKey=<Key>
sonar.projectName=<ProjectName>
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=./TestResult.xml